# How to display a clickable link on an Oracle Apex Form

Tags: hyperlink, apex

I'm using Apex 19.1 on an 18.C database.
I have an Apex form with the type of "Table / View".  One of the fields on that table is `VIDEO_LINK`.  I'm trying to display the contents of that field.  The field values all start with     `https://`
How do I display that value on a form?  The page item P223_VIDEO_LINK has the following characteristics:
Identification / Type = `Display Only`
Setting / Based On = `Page Item Value`
Source / Column = `VIDEO_LINK`
(I've tried a number of things like:)
Advanced / Pre Text =      `&lt;a href="&P223_VIDEO_LINK.">`
Advanced / Post Text =     `&lt;/a>`
But none produce expected results.  How do I display a clickable link on a display-only page item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Pre and Post text values from the page item P222_video_link and setup a Dynamic Action (DA) with the following characteristics:

```
Identification / Name = Update P222_video_link
When / Event = Page Load
Action = True
Identification / Action = Execute PL/SQL Code
Settings / PL/SQL Code =


DECLARE
   l_initial_value   varchar2(1024);
BEGIN
   l_initial_value := :P222_video_link;
   :P222_video_link := '<a href="' || l_initial_value|| '" target="_blank">' || l_initial_value || '</a>';
END;


Settings / Items To Submit = P222_VIDEO_LINK
Settings / Items To Return = P222_VIDEO_LINK
```

The page item P222_VIDEO_LINK has the following characteristics:

```
Identification / Type = Display Only
Security / Escape special characters = No
```

That fixed the problem.